# Setting up aliases to use GitHub from the command line

Tags: unix, github, alias, command-prompt

I have set up some aliases in my `~/.bash_profile` file for simple GitHub tasks such as:

```
gp="git push"
gs="git status"
```

I would like to be able to set two more for `git add` and `git commit` so that it will ask me for input.

```
ga="git add" -> Which file(s) would you like to add? $path_to_file
gc="git commit -m" -> Please add a message: $user_input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to use a function in `~/.bash_profile` instead of an alias.

For example, something like this can make it:

```
git_commit () {
        read -p "Add a message? " -r user_input
        git commit -m "$user_input"
}
```

Comment: Do I use `gc=git_commit()` then?

Comment: You can directly call it with `git_commit`.

Comment: Can I set an alias for it though so I only have to type `gc`?

Comment: Yes, sure, you can do `gc=git_commit` (without `()`, note!). Or you can also call the function just `gc`.

Comment: Thank you, that's great. What about the `git add`, is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is very obvious, just change `git commit` for `git  add` :)